# Display Rate Module in Drupal 7 Template

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, rate

In Drupal 6 if I want to display the RATE module, I can use the code (

```
<?php print $node->rate_rate['#value'];?>
```

What is the code to display it in Drupal 7 template?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can choose to not automatically add the widget to the node template. In that
case, the widget can be used as:

```
<?php print $node->rate_NAME['#markup']; ?>
```

Replace NAME by the widget's machine readable name.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Drupal 7.26 `Notice: Undefined property:  stdClass::$rate_votepage`